# IE 7 jQuery image load bug

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer-7, load

I'm loading an image into a blank  tag and keep getting the following IE 7 Error: reader.load -> error loading image: http://localhost/uploads/239-4/SCAN_0001.jpg

I'm running jQuery 1.7.1 and the following to load the image:

```
prop.image.attr('src', 'http://localhost/uploads/239-4/SCAN_0001.jpg').load(function(e) {
if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
    alert('foobar x.x');
}
else { alert('image loaded yay \o/'); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to remove the conditional check for this.complete, typeof this.naturalWidth, and this.naturalWidth. Which somewhat sucks because we want to have some sort of fall back for if the image doesn't load.

```
prop.image.attr('src', 'http://localhost/uploads/239-4/SCAN_0001.jpg').load(function(e) { alert('image loaded yay \o/'); });
```